# Is there a way to modify internal .dockerignore file when you do a build?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerignore

I'm trying to build a image from a remote repository in which i don't have any access at all, thing is in my Dockerfile build i have a command like this:

`COPY license.md /licenses/`

but i think that license.md is introduced before that line in

```
[+] Building 1.5s (7/9)                                                                                                                                                                             docker:default
```

```
 => [internal] load .dockerignore
```

So how can i undo that file to be in license.md from Dockerfile or build commands? I can somehow go in internal .dockerignore file and remove it from there?

Tried everything but this is a possible solution, i think

Comment: If you can't modify any of the source this seems hard to do.  If you can check out the repository locally, then you could modify the `.dockerignore` file before running `docker build`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! Is there a way to check for docker logs internally, i mean in linux vm? I somehow make the build of docker image pass but when i run it containers stops... and no logs whatsoever, what can i do?